# Outer join and using Oracle indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  t1,  t2 , t3
WHERE t1.row_id = t2.invoice_id(+)
and t2.voi_id = t3.row_id(+)
and type = 'Dec'
order by 1
```

I have 3 indexes, one for each column in the join, but it seems that the explain plan uses a full table scan on the tables without using the indexes:

Plan

```
1 Every row in the table t1  is read.
2 The rows were sorted to support the join at step 5.
3 Every row in the table t2  is read.
4 The rows were sorted to support the join at step 5.
5 Join the sorted results sets provided from steps 2, 4.
6 Rows were returned by the SELECT statement.
```

Comment: There need to be enough rows in the table to justify using an index before  Oracle will decide to use one.

Comment: You might want to try using an Oracle hint to see if it changes the Explain Plan - SELECT /*+ INDEX(t1 t1_index_name_here) */ * FROM t1, t2, t3 ...

Comment: It would help if the standard explain plan format was used.  Run `explain plan for select * ...;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and add the *entire* output to the question.

Comment: That can't be the execution plan, where is the filtering by type? If that is pushed so it's done early, as it should be, not using the indexes may be optimal. Which table has the type column?

Comment: Why don't you show us the **real** plan? (as _formatted_ **text** please, no screen shots)

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on rowcounts and size of tables. In your query all rows t1 will be fetched (because used left join and all rows from t1 with type='Dec' will be shown). That's why *TABLE ACCESS FULL* to table t1 is normal.

If rowcount in t1 is more than 20-30% rowcount in t2 (% depend on t2 size) also *TABLE ACCESS FULL* to t2 and their *hash join* is normal scenario.